# Algorithm: Randomize Brightness and Contrast Values, With Constraints

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, random

I want to do a random brightness and contrast adjustment to an image, such that...

```
brightness = random in range (brightness_min, brightness_max)
contrast = random in range (contrast_min, contrast_max)   
outputImage = inputImage * contrast + brightness;
```

But when I do this, because the range of brightness and contrast values in my application are so large, I often output an image which is all white or all black.

I want an algorithm to choose a random brightness and contrast pair such that: no output is a solid color (unless already so), and: the output retains some specifiable amount of detail (this part is less important).

I don't know how to describe what I want in technical terms, nor begin constructing the solution. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What stops you from limiting the ranges you pick your parameters (`brightness` and `contrast`) from? Seems like the simplest solution to this problem.

Comment: The brightness and contrast values are settable by the user, and are necessarily large in order to be able to produce extreme effects with a single adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `brightness`, `inputImage`, and `outputImage` are all on the same scale, I'd change the formula for `outputImage` to

```
outputImage = (inputImage - averageInputImage) * contrast + brightness;
```

where `averageInputImage` is the average (mean, median, whatever makes sense) of the `inputImage` values. Assuming positive contrast and an input image with detail, the output should have *some* detail, even if for high contrast it is alternately white and black.